# SQL Server 2008 R2 differential backups much larger than expected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

We have several SQL Server 2008 R2 databases for which we perform a full backup every Sunday then differential backups Monday to Saturday. We also do transaction log backups every 10 minutes.

The first differential backup on Monday is usually quite small, but Tuesday to Saturday are much larger but similar in size to each other.

I used some scripts I found which predict the differential backup size, e.g. https://dougzuck.com/sql-differential-backup-size-prediction and http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/new-script-how-much-of-the-database-has-changed-since-the-last-full-backup/, and they predict a very much smaller backup size.

Examples are:

```
database1, full backup size 5Gb, diff size 3.5Gb, predicted diff size 84Mb
database2, full backup size 40Gb, diff size 1Gb, predicted diff size 17Mb
```

As you can see, the actual sizes are hugely different and can be half the size of the full backup after only a couple of days.

I know users aren't creating or modifying the actual data to any great extent. As far as I can tell, there are no index rebuilds or other management tasks happening between the full and differential backups.

It's like something is happening on Monday which causes the Tuesday onward differentials to be huge. Backup compression is not used.

Any ideas?? Thanks in advance.

Doug

Comment: I would ask this question in http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

How differential backup works..?

Whenever we take a differential backup,it copies all the changes which occured from last full backup,Not from Last differential backup..

That is the reason why you are seeing "*actual sizes are hugely different and can be half the size of the full backup after only a couple of days*"

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Yes, I understand what you are saying. Each differential backup gets it's own file and I would expect that each file gets a bit bigger than the last. But it doesn't explain why the amount of data changing is a few Mb but the differential backup file is several Gb. Doug.

Comment: Backup contains datafiles and ldf required to bring the data back to cosistency..So in your case there might be transactions which are happening on day to day basis and rolling back ,but not happening to full backup